# Gelfand transform of $a \in A$ vanishes at infinity?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

Let $A$ be a non-unital commutative Banach algebra defined over the field  of complex numbers.

Given $a \in A$, one defines the function $\widehat{a}:\Phi_A\to{\mathbb C}$ by $\widehat{a}(\varphi)=\varphi(a)$, where $\Phi_A$ is endowed with the Gelfand topology (i.e. the restriction of the $w^*$-topology on $A^*$ to $\Phi_A$).

The definition of $\Phi_A$ and of its topology ensure that $\widehat{a}$ is continuous. According to wiki  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation)
it seems that $\widehat{a} \in \mathcal{C}_0(\Phi_A)$, that is to say that $\widehat{a}$ vanishes at infinity. I struggle to see why this latter fact is true.

Answer (score 2):

**Since nobody posted an answer, I will write down my attempt. Could anyone check is this is correct please ?**

Note that $\big\{ \varphi \in \Phi_A :~~ \big| \varphi(a)\big| \geq \varepsilon \big\}$ is $w^*$-closed in the closed unit ball of $A^*$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ because

$$\big\{ \varphi \in \Phi_A :~~ \big| \varphi(a)\big| \geq \varepsilon \big\} = \widehat{a}^{-1}\Big( \{z : |z| \geq \varepsilon\}\Big)$$
and $\{z : |z| \geq \varepsilon\}$ is closed and $\widehat{a}$ is continuous when $\Phi_A$ has the Gelfand topology.

Hence Banach-Alaoglu implies that $\big\{ \varphi \in \Phi_A :~~ \big| \varphi(a)\big| \geq \varepsilon \big\}$ is $w^*$-compact.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. I have a question: $\tag*{}$ Don't you want to say $\widehat{a}$ is continuous, instead of "$\widehat{a}^{-1}$ is continuous"?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited. It's probably a copy/paste typo.

Comment: I don't know if it could be of any interest to you, but your proof is very similar to the one of the theorem 7.3 in [_An Introduction to Operator Algebras_ by Kehe Zhu](https://books.google.ch/books?id=XHLj7bz8hOIC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=gelfand+transform+non+unital&source=bl&ots=gg5GTj05N2&sig=dvgCG7D2eLxuJAvLrFhjJufeQpg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD1IP79PzLAhWKECwKHXMNAo0Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)