# Fourier / Gelfand transform vanishes at infinity?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, compactification, gelfand-representation

I've come across the fact that the Fourier transform (or, more general, the Gelfand transform) vanishes at $\infty$. See for example "Principles of Harmonic Analysis" by Deitmar and Echterhoff, page 47 or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation). I also found the following two related posts:
(1) [Gelfand transform of $a \in A$ vanishes at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577215/gelfand-transform-of-a-in-a-vanishes-at-infinity/4642814#4642814), (2) [Range of the Gelfand transform on a non-unital Banach algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761966/range-of-the-gelfand-transform-on-a-non-unital-banach-algebra/4642926?noredirect=1#comment9800710_4642926).
But I am not satisfied with the arguments and I am looking for a convincing proof. It would be great if someone could give me some hints!

I'm going to restrict myself to the case where $A = L^1(G)$, i.e., I will just look at the Fourier transform, but the general case is similar. Let $f \in L^1(G)$ and $G$ be a locally compact abelian group.

First, about (1) and (2): Both use that $B = \widehat{f}^{-1}(\mathbb{C} \setminus B_\varepsilon(0))$ is a weak* closed subset of $\sigma(L^1)$. Since $\sigma(L^1) \cup \{0\}$ is weak* compact, they claim that $B$ must be weak* compact in $\sigma(L^1)$. But since the set is not necessarily closed in the superset, I don't see why that should hold. Is there a way to fix this argument?

About the approach in the book, which I also found in some other books: There, they use that $\sigma(L^1) \cup \{0\}$ is the one-point-compactification of $\sigma(L^1)$ and that vanishing at infinity is the same as the continuous extension of $\widehat{f}$ satisfying $\widehat{f}(0) =0$. All of them just state that $\widehat{f}(0) =0$ is obvious. My question here is: How can I prove that this is the actual continuous extension? I tried to show that it is continuous in $0$ but I somehow got stuck. I'm working with the formula $\widehat{f}(\xi) = h_\xi(f)= \int_G \overline{\langle x, \xi \rangle} f(x) \ dx$, where $\xi \in \widehat{G}$. I know that we can use $\widehat{G}$ with the topology of compact convergence and $\sigma(L^1)$ with the weak* topology interchangeably. For $\varepsilon > 0$, we have

$$\widehat{f}^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(\widehat{f}(0))) 
= \widehat{f}^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(0))
= \{\eta \in \widehat{G} \cup \{0\} \mid |\widehat{f}(\eta)| < \varepsilon\}\\
\cong \{h_\eta \in \sigma(L^1) \cup \{0\} \mid |h_\eta(f)| < \varepsilon\}
= \{h_\eta \in \sigma(L^1) \mid |h_\eta(f)| < \varepsilon\} \cup \{0\}.
$$
But why is the latter open in the one-point-compactification $\sigma(L^1) \cup \{0\}$?

I am thankful for any hints!

Comment: Do you mean
 $\mathcal{F}[L^1(G)]\subset C_0^0(\widehat{G})$ where $L^1(G)$ means integral wrt the Haar measure, $\widehat{G}$ is the continuous homomorphisms $G\to S^1\subset \Bbb{C}^*$ with the topology of compact convergence, $\mathcal{F}[f](\phi)=\phi(f)$ and $C^0_0$ means the closure for the $\sup$ norm of the continuous compactly supported functions

Comment: Mimicking the proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for $G=\Bbb{R}$: $2\hat{f}(n)=\int_\Bbb{R} (f(x)-f(x-1/(2n)))e^{-2i\pi xn}dx \le \|f-f(.-1/(2n))\|_{L^1} $ the proof for arbirtrary $G$ follows from $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{g\in U_n}\|f-f(.-g)\|_{L^1(G)}=0$ where $U_n$ is a basis of neighborhoods of $0_G$.

Comment: Perhaps Lemma 2.3 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/loccptascoli.pdf will be of interest to you.

Comment: @reuns: Yes, that is what I meant. Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't completely see how that follows. In the proof you mentioned, one uses $e^{i\pi}= -1$, but in this general case, we don't have that. We get 
$$2 \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_G (f(x) + \langle g, \xi \rangle f(xg^{-1})) \overline{\langle x, \xi \rangle} \ dx$$
for $g \in G$ and then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: If $\phi\in V_n = \{ \chi \in \widehat{G},\exists g\in U_n,\chi(g)=-1\}$  then $2\hat{f}(\phi)=\int_G (f(x)-f(x-g))\phi(x)dx\le C_n=\sup_{g\in U_n} \|f-f(.-g)\|_{L^1}$. As $\lim_n C_n=0$ this means that the continuous functions supported on some $\widehat{G}-V_n$ for some $n$ are dense in the closure of $\widehat{L^1(G)}$ for the $\sup$ norm.

Comment: But how can I use this to prove that $\mathcal{F}(L^1)$ lies in $C_0(\widehat{G})$? Since $\widehat{G}\setminus V_n$ might not be compact, I don't know how this could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt on fixing the first approach:

Let $f \in L^1(G)$. We extend $\hat{f}: \widehat{G} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to a function $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}: \widehat{G}\cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by defining $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(0) = h_0(f) = 0$. We claim that this extension is continuous.

Indeed, let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and choose some $\xi \in \hat{f}_{\text{ext}}^{-1}(U) \subset \widehat{G}\cup \{0\} $. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B_\varepsilon(\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(\xi))$ lies in $U$. Now, it suffices to prove that $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(\xi))) \subset \widehat{G} \cup \{0\}$ is open. We have
$$\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}^{-1}(B_\varepsilon(\widehat{f}_{\text{ext}}(\xi))) 
= \big\{\eta \in \widehat{G}\cup\{0\} \mid \big\vert \hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(\xi)- \hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(\eta)\big\vert < \varepsilon\big\} \cong \big\{h_\eta \in \sigma(L^1(G))\cup \{0\} \mid \left\vert h_\xi(f)- h_\eta(f)\right\vert < \varepsilon\big\}. $$
The latter is weak*-open in $\sigma(L^1(G))\cup \{0\}$, so the left-hand side is open in $\widehat{G}\cup \{0\}$. Thus, $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}$ is continuous.

Now, let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}$ is continuous, the set $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}^{-1}(\mathbb{C} \setminus B_\varepsilon(0))$ is closed. As a subset of the compact set $\widehat{G}\cup \{0\}$ it is compact. Since $\hat{f}_{\text{ext}}(0) = 0$, we have $\hat{f}^{-1}(\mathbb{C} \setminus B_\varepsilon(0)) = \hat{f}_{\text{ext}}^{-1}(\mathbb{C} \setminus B_\varepsilon(0))$. Since these sets are compact in $\widehat{G} \cup \{0\}$, they are also compact in $\widehat{G}$. Therefore, $\hat{f}$ vanishes at infinity.

Any concerns?